# Flash Builder: "Access of undefined property Bindable"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding, flash-builder

I have inherited an Adobe AIR application, and am attempting to debug it through Flash Builder 4.5. Within Flash Builder, when I look at one of the MXML files, I see warnings for each use of the `[Bindable]` tag:

```
[Bindable]
internal var selectedPreviousID:String=null;

[Bindable]
internal var recent:mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
```

The warning is:

> Access of undefined property Bindable

There is an import for what I believe to be the appropriate library:

> import mx.binding.utils.*;

And there are no missing semi-colons on the lines preceding each warning as per the suggestion in [this blog post](http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2007/03/19/fix-1120-access-of-undefined-property-bindable/).

The project is configured to use Flex SDK 3.6.

Additionally the file will not load in the designer, with this warning:

> Design mode: Error during component layout. Choose Design > Refresh to refresh design mode.

What am I missing? At runtime I am seeing a blank window - which I assume is the result of the bindings not being triggered. Is this tag not available in Flex SDK 3.6?

Comment: could you post an example of how the bindable tags are exactly used? (and you can try [Bindable()], that might solve the problem).

Comment: First, don't use designer, it's crap IMO.  Pure code is more viewable. As for the warnings on Bindable, you shouldn't have a problem since Bindable is an integral part of Flex unless you mistyped something and the parser think you're referencing something else.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a sample of the code in question. I can't paste the entire class here due to copyright. I have tried [Bindable()] and it makes no difference.

Comment: This might be IDE install problem. [Bindable] is metadata, not property, IDE has gone mad. Does Bindable work in clean project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing elements from the code one by one, I discovered that the warnings somehow appear to have been caused by an `<mx:WebService>` element declaration earlier:

```
<mx:WebServiceid="service"
    wsdl="https://blah.com/blah?WSDL"
    operations='{{"Op1":this.method1()}}'/>
</mx:WebService>
```

Specifically, if I remove the inline 'operations' attribute - then the warnings against Bindable disappear. Must be triggering some issue with the parser.

Further testing reveals that **any** attributes that use the inline attribute syntax, e.g.:

```
properties='{{"outerDocument":this}}'
```

Trigger this parser issue. This code was generated by a decompiler, so it may be that it is not valid.

There is an alternative syntax for specifying the operations as XML nodes instead of an attribute:

```
<mx:WebServiceid="service"
    wsdl="https://blah.com/blah?WSDL"/>
    <mx:operation name="Op1" result="this.method1(event)">
    <mx:request>
        <token>{credentials.token}</token>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:operation>
</mx:WebService>
```